Did Boeing's Starliner do an inflight abort test?
Did the Starliner perform an inflight abort test? I could not find any videos to support the same. Isn't a pad abort and an in flight abort neccesary before sending humans to space? Can the starliner's launch escape engines accelerate the vehicle when the Atlas V's SRB are burning?


Did the Starliner perform an inflight abort test?

No.

Isn't a pad abort and an in flight abort neccesary before sending humans to space?

Not if it's not in the contract.

Can the starliner's launch escape engines accelerate the vehicle when the Atlas V's SRB are burning?

I certainly hope so.

“Boeing is not going to do an in-flight abort test,” said Jon Cowart, deputy manager of the mission management office for NASA’s commercial crew program, before the pad abort test. “They’re just going to do the ground one. They think that they can get enough data and then extrapolate that out, with good analytical techniques that we’ve endorsed. They will go and do it in that particular way, versus SpaceX, which is going to do both.
“We knew about this up front, both Boeing and SpaceX, when they proposed their contracts to us and said, ‘This is how we’re going to get to real flights,'” Cowart said last week in a NASA podcast. “We understood exactly, and we bought into it. We think, and we agree with them, that we can get all they need from a pad-abort test.”

https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/11/04/boeing-starliner-pad-abort/

NASA trusts them like the FAA trusted them? I hope the guys in the Starliner program have a better culture than on the aircraft side of the company…

Trusting Boeing on this one seems like a pretty silly thing to do in hindsight... Wonder if this causes some sleepless nights for some people at NASA or Boeing...

@jcaron the first orbital test of Starliner that went wrong because of an issue that should have been trivial to detect in a simulation didn't boost my trust in the ability of Boeig to properly simulate anything!

@TrySCE2AUX I could not agree more about the shoddiness of their simulation.

@jcaron, OFT-1 and 737 MAX MCAS were developed while Boeing had a much lower amount of oversight which was based on a trust with those agencies that had built up over decades. When these incidents exposed that Boeing had serious problems with its safety culture and organization, both NASA and FAA pivoted into a very different relationship with much more oversight. I'm pretty sure that NASA has now looked much closer at the data and rationale that Boeing used for not doing an in-flight abort test. Hopefully they looked at it objectively in spite of pressure to get a second capsule flying.

@TrySCE2AUX - the test would not have been trivial as it would have required linking the simulation software for the two different systems to run concurrently. Was that type of simulation necessary? Absolutely. Just not as easy as it sounds. But by not taking the extra effort to do a coordinated simulation it cost them big time in the long run.

@StevePemberton They had a integrated simulation of the booster and capsule, they just never ran it for the full duration launch -> docking.  They cut the sim off at capsule separation. Hey, that probably saved them a few thousand bucks. /s https://aerospaceamerica.aiaa.org/boeing-starliner-error-would-have-been-caught-with-expanded-testing/

@StevePemberton true, i worded that not precisely enough. The issue would have been trivial to find if they had run the (non trivial) silulation. It's not "something that they could have missed" was what I meant.

OrganicMarble - I thought I remembered that for some reason a full test would be time consuming, Perhaps the complication of merging the two systems was made more feasible by breaking the simulations into chunks like they did. If not and it was just a management convenience to break it into chunks, over the objections of the engineers, then it does veer more towards being a trivial modification to their test procedure that could have been done.

@StevePemberton Well, yeah, running the sim for several hours is more time consuming than running it for 10 minutes. But "Going forward, for every flight, we will do launch to docking and undocking to landing in addition to the other tests we were doing in our qualification testing.”

OrganicMarble - I was referring to test development time not simulation run time. The article that you linked indicated that even the engineers were apparently in favor of breaking it into chunks. They presumably had their reasons for this. Afterwards even the least competent engineers and managers can realize in hindsight that the full test should have been done. I wonder what the reasons were though. Clearly the reasons were not sufficient, especially in hindsight, but I still suspect that it wasn't as trivial as just getting to go home two hours earlier.

NASA institutionally prefers analysis to testing. Test failures are embarrassing.

@TrySCE2AUX: It also would not have caused loss of mission (let alone loss of vehicle) on a crewed flight.

@Joshua "the crew would've noticed and taken over!"  too bad the small army of engineers monitoring the vehicle and flying it from the ground couldn't do that. That might've been a good idea

@ErinAnne: I'm pretty sure they didn't have the capacity to direct control from the ground, bypassing the computer stabilization altogether. Imperfect radio links make building that ability a bad idea, so they don't. But on board is a different story. The crew just sets control to manual and largely allows stabilization to drift until it actually matters at the point of the mission.

@Joshua " Imperfect radio links make building that ability a bad idea, so they don't. " Um, every NASA human spacecraft since Gemini had that capability

@OrganicMarble: Really? I highly doubt they have a remote stick set up to let them hand fly from the ground. They had ground control capacity but that depended on the computer's ability to do ATT hold first. This particular save means turning ATT hold off; and most likely couldn't be used at all when on the other side of Earth because your latency is now too high.

@Joshua All they needed to do to fix Starliner was uplink the right clock time. They just figured it out too late.

From Eric Berger's interesting article on the history of Starliner at ArsTechnica: "There was no single flight software team at Boeing ... A team at Kennedy Space Center in Florida handled the ground systems software ...Separately, a team at Boeing's facilities in Houston near Johnson Space Center managed the flight software for when the vehicle took off ... Neither team trusted one another"  https://arstechnica.com/space/2024/05/the-surprise-is-not-that-boeing-lost-commercial-crew-but-that-it-finished-at-all/
